# How do I set SystemCapabilities in RubyMotion?

Tags: rubymotion

What is the correct way, in a RubyMotion context to set the `SystemCapabilities` dictionary usually set automatically by `Xcode`in the `project.pbxproj` file.

I'm talking about this dictionary specifically. And how do you set their sub values as seen in the attached screenshot of Xcode6.

```
SystemCapabilities = {
    com.apple.ApplicationGroups.iOS = {
      enabled = 1;
    };
    com.apple.BackgroundModes = {
      enabled = 1;
    };
    com.apple.DataProtection = {
      enabled = 1;
    };
    com.apple.GameCenter = {
      enabled = 1;
    };
    com.apple.HealthKit = {
      enabled = 1;
    };
    com.apple.HomeKit = {
      enabled = 1;
    };
    com.apple.InAppPurchase = {
      enabled = 1;
    };
    com.apple.InterAppAudio = {
      enabled = 1;
    };
    com.apple.Keychain = {
      enabled = 1;
    };
    com.apple.Maps.iOS = {
      enabled = 1;
    };
    com.apple.OMC = {
      enabled = 1;
    };
    com.apple.Passbook = {
      enabled = 1;
    };
    com.apple.SafariKeychain = {
      enabled = 1;
    };
    com.apple.VPNLite = {
      enabled = 1;
    };
    com.apple.WAC = {
      enabled = 1;
    };
    com.apple.iCloud = {
      enabled = 1;
    };
  };
};
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Inside `Motion::Project::App.setup do |app|` block in your rakefile

`app.entitlements['com.apple.developer.healthkit'] = true`

For some capabilities you'll also need to add the framework, and can optionally set info_plist properties.

For Healthkit specifically, 

`app.frameworks << 'HealthKit'
app.info_plist['UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities'] = ['healthkit'] # This will limit supported to devices to iphone 5s+, and is optional`